# Is there a free heart rate monitor for iPhone 5 that will notify me if I exceed a specific heart rate?

Tags: heart-rate, target-heart-rate, heart-rate-monitor, app

I'm not usually able to look at my phone when I'm working out so I was wondering if there is a heart rate monitor, or heart rate monitor and app combination, that will let me know if I exceed a heart rate I designate in real time by vibrating or emitting a sound notification.

Comment: Did you do any research at all? This is one of the most common features of nearly every heart rate monitor out there.

Comment: I read through Amazon reviews of the most popular monitors and did not notice any mention of this feature.

Comment: The advice below is more or less the same for iPhone, simply substitute Google for iTunes App store. You'll see the likes of: [Heart Rate Monitor++](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/heart-rate-monitor-++/id880670810?mt=8) and [Heart Graph](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/heart-graph/id591655999?mt=8)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't do shopping recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

There are many, simply Google: **Heart Rate Zone alarm**  or alternitively **Cardio Trainer** and you'll get the likes of [Cardio Trainer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.angel.heartmonitorfree.activities) or [Heart Rate and Pulse Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.hoelting.athletegrip.heartline). Oh, you haven't said which flavour of device / phone, you're looking for.